# Bizzare std::distance output

Tags: c++, qt, stl, iterator

I have taken this little snippet straight out of some code I'm working on:

```
KeyIter it = timeline_.lowerBound( frame );
if ( timeline_.isKeyAtFrame( frame ) ) {
    ++it;
}

KeyIter it1 = it - 1;
cout << "dist1: " << std::distance( timeline_.begin(), it1 ) << endl;
while ( ignore.contains( it1.key() ) ) {
    cout << "dist2: " << std::distance( timeline_.begin(), it1 - 1 ) << endl;
    if ( std::distance( timeline_.begin(), --it1 ) < 0 ) {
        break;
    }
}
cout << "dist3: " << std::distance( timeline_.begin(), it1 ) << endl;
```

It gives this output:

```
dist1: 0
dist2: 2
dist3: 2
```

`ignore` is a `QSet<int>` and `it1` is an iterator for `timeline_` (it's map type with a key of `int`).  As you can see `it1` starts at the beginning (this is correct), then control goes into the while loop where the iterator is moved backwards by one; but instead of std::distance being -1, it's 2!  All that happens inbetween is a copy of the key is used to check if the `QSet` contains the same `int`.

Using a debugger I can confirm that `timeline_` does not change inbetween the two `dist#` outputs (only one thread is running at this point in the code anyway).

Can anyone see why `std::distance` would be giving this output?

Comment: What type exactly is `timeline_`?  You said it's a map, but if it's `std::map`, then `it1` is certainly not one of its iterators.  (as `std::map` iterators do not support operations such ase `it1.key()` or `it1 - 1`) -- So what map class is it actually?  (Edit: I've just looked at the documentation for `QMap`, and I guess it's probably that, right?)

Comment: I don't see where `it` is being initialized (nor declared). Assuming `it=_timeline.begin()` I also wonder how valid it is to substract -1 from `it`.

Comment: Thanks for your responses, yes @BenjaminLindley `it` and `it1` are `QMap::ConstIterator`s.  @CarstenGreiner I added `it`'s declaration to the code, its created by a lower bound query (which would put it at the beginning of the map for the data I am using it on) but it is then increased by 1 to makes it's behaviour the same when used for 'inter' key querying.  This is part of a method that gets the two neighbours either side of a query point, but skipping past keys also referenced in separate list (`ignore`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about Qt's behavior on this, but in standard library containers, aquiring an iterator outside the range `[container.begin(),container.end()]` is undefined behavior.  I would assume it's the same in Qt, though I'm not sure.  However, even if it's not, the behavior of `std::distance` on non-random access iterators is to count the number of **increments** required to get from the first iterator to the last, so this:

```
std::distance(x,y)
```

where `y` precedes `x`, is undefined behavior.

Comment: I'm not acquiring the iterator outside of the range, but I am expecting `std::distance` to be able to count backwards on bidirectional iterators - which I now know it can't.  Thank you!

Comment: @cbamber85: If you are expecting a result of `-1` with the call `std::distance( timeline_.begin(), --it1 )`, then you are expecting `it1` to precede `timeline_.begin()` by 1 element.  Is that not outside the range `[timeline_.begin(), timeline_.end()]`?

Comment: When you said "acquire" I thought you meant initialise an iterator outside of the range, as opposed to move one outside the range.